# Plotting age group with gender with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset of credit history. 
[image: german credit history]

How to plot the age group (applied for loan) for each gender using ggplot2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot)
german_credit$Sex <- as.factor(german_credit$Sex)
ggplot(german_credit, aes(x = Age)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~Sex)
```